# Python struct unpack with irregular field sizes

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, struct, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to unpack a struct containing some metadata and an image. It's all bits, but the way that contents were packed is quite strange. Instead of elements being aligned on a byte, they're aligned on every 6 bits. The file format and contents are listed in the image below and can be also accessed at the link: http://etlcdb.db.aist.go.jp/etlcdb/etln/form_c.htm.

The only fields that I am interested in are the JIS code and the 16 gray level image data that is the last field. This data is taken from http://etlcdb.db.aist.go.jp/etlcdb/etln/etl4/etl4.htm.

The main problem that I'm facing is the fact that the fields are 6 bit aligned. I don't know how to properly unpack the struct.

As an aside, with PIL, it's also unclear how to handle 4 bit images. The mode 1 isn't working correctly, as expected..

[image: file format]

```
import struct
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

filename = 'ETL4/ETL4C'
skip = 0
record_size = 2952
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        f.seek(skip * record_size)
        s = f.read(record_size)
        r = struct.unpack('>9x1i203x2736s', s)
        print r[1]
        i1 = Image.frombytes('1', (72, 76), r[1], 'raw')
        # fn = 'ETL9B_{:d}_{:d}.png'.format((r[0]-1)%20+1, hex(r[1])[-4:])
        fn = 'name1.png'
        i1.save(fn, 'PNG')
```

Comment: Not sure if you can achieve this with `struct`. Best thing that comes into my mind, is read 3 bytes at once, and using bit operations (shifting and masking) extract 4 6bit values.

Comment: I believe you can use struct to extract the image pixels as 2736 bytes. Then, since the image is 4 bit pixels, you should be able to process each of those 2736 bytes into 2 bytes by using bit operations to extract the upper 4 bits and lower 4 bits into 2 new 8-bit bytes creating 5472 new bytes. Then you should be able to use the 'L' mode of Image.frombytes() on the new bytes. You would likely have to do some image processing after that to fix the brightness of the image.